# Wordpress :TypeError: window.tinyMCE.execInstanceCommand is not a function

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I can't add any shortcode in my wordpress editor. it shows -

```
TypeError: window.tinyMCE.execInstanceCommand is not a function

window.tinyMCE.execInstanceCommand(id, 'mceInsertContent', false, shortcode)
```

. please help me to solve this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TypeError: window.tinyMCE.execInstanceCommand is not a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813970/typeerror-window-tinymce-execinstancecommand-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0):

The TinyMCE API changed after version 4.

(assuming, that you have jQuery 1.7 or above)

```
jQuery(window).on("load", function(){
    // First get the loaded TinyMCE version:
    var mceVersion = parseInt(tinyMCE.majorVersion);

    // ...

    // Then later in your code where you want to insert your content:
    if(mceVersion >= 4){
        tinyMCE.execCommand("mceInsertContent", false, shortcode);
    }else{
        tinyMCE.execInstanceCommand("content", "mceInsertContent", false, shortcode);
    }
});
```